# unexpected child flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, assets

i tried the ways i found to solve this error
.i know there is a problem in my indentation. but i need a guidance now.
-- flutter version: latest
-- android studio version: -latest
flutter upgrade ->done

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try changing

```
  asets:
```

to

```
  assets:
```